# Python: Having trouble reading in a file when prompted

Tags: python, file-io

I am having issues reading in a file. I prompt the user to load a file and then use the input as an argument in a function which simply attempts to load the given filename and print each line.
I am receiving an IOError: No such file or directory: 'filename.txt'

```
filename = raw_input("Filename to load: ")
print load_records(students, filename)

def load_records(students, filename):
    #loads student records from a file
    records = []
    in_file = open(filename, "r")
    for line in in_file:
        print line
```

I suspect that I am not accessing the correct directory.

Comment: what is the content that gets saved in the filename variable ? if your using windows , you need to replace "\" by "\\" , to define the directory.

Comment: @thecreator232 That's only the case in Python literals (and that can be overcome with raw strings). When typing a path on standard in, doubling the slashes to escape them is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Given the error, I will conclude that you typed nothing but `filename.txt` when prompted. This will cause Python to search for a file named `filename.txt` in the *current directory*. So if your command prompt's current directory is `C:\dev`, this is equivalent to `C:\dev\filename.txt` (the absolute path). You should either change the current directory to the directory containing `filename.txt` or specific the absolute path when prompted. The latter would probably be simpler as it wouldn't be as likely to mess up Python's ability to find your other modules.

Comment: When I type in the entire file path, I am given a Value Error: mixing iteration and read methods would lose data.

Comment: @user3271700 Then it appears that specifying the full path has allowed your program to successfully open the file. I believe the new error warrants a separate question since it will probably require more details and discussion.